# Sending files to SSH client over SSH using SCP

Tags: linux, ssh, copy, scp

The situation is that my client machine does not use static IP but the server machine is using static IP.

I connect to the server machine using ssh from the client machine.

Are there any easy ways to send files from the server machine to the client machine using scp or other commands?

I want to execute commands inside the server.

Comment: Have you not just answered your own question? If you can successfully use ssh, you should be able to use scp.

Comment: I wanna use the commands inside the server instead of the clients

Answer (score 0):

You can scp from the client machine and get the file from the server.

client$ scp user@server:< path to file > < path to destination folder in client >

eg, if you want file1 in the home directory from the server copied to the current directory in your client, you can do the following:

$ scp user@server:~/file1 .

ref: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/

Comment: I could do it on my client machine. But I wanna do that in the sever machine

Comment: You can use ngrock to get your client machine's ssh port accessible by the server and then run the command on the server. The free plan should work.
You may follow this tutorial: https://www.endtoend.ai/tutorial/ngrok-ssh-forwarding/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to connect using the ssh command, you can connect using the sftp command (ftp-like interface through an ssh connection):

```
$ sftp user@server
```

And then just use the command get:

```
sftp> get <file>
```

Commands like ls, cd and pwd also work in this sftp interface.